# Rebol shift-tab side effects

Tags: rebol2

Given this:
    view layout [ field [print "1" ] field [print "2"] ]

When I shift+tab from field #2 to field #1, no actions are fired.
How do I get them to fire just like a normal tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in the key handler for `field` style in the Rebol/View engine. Here is a quick patch you can include in your code to fix it and make SHIFT+Tab work:

```
use [body f pos][
    ;-- patch `ctx-text/back-field` function to fix the bug
    body: copy/deep second f: get in ctx-text 'back-field
    insert body/2/while [if head? item [item: tail item]]
    ctx-text/back-field: func first :f :body

    ;-- remove test that disables face/action for back-tabs
    body: second get in ctx-text 'edit-text
    body: find body 'word?
    pos: at body/3/7/tab-char/5/6 11
    change/part pos pos/4 4
]
```

This code will walk through View engine functions at run-time (code is data in Rebol) and hot-patch the functions bodies, by injecting or removing code where required.

If you happen to be a Rebol/SDK user, I can give you the instructions for patching the source files directly, so you can encap a fixed View executable.

Enjoy.

Comment: Good thing I asked. I have no idea about any of this but it sure resolved my problem - Thanks.